# sharepoint list missing / features deactivated

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am facing a huge problem with Sharepoint Online. We have two sites and both of them have the same solution deployed. Both solution are subsites and have their features at web scope.

The solution has a main list that we put some data in it depending on some rules but as it is not part of the main issues this is not important.

The problem is that recently something really annoying is happening in these environments. This main list, usually during the week and during the morning is being deleted, and also the features of the solution are being deactivated.

The team came up with some ideias about what is happening:

1. Some code in the solution that delete the main list.
2. Someone is deleting the main list (someone really bad).
3. List is being deleted by a sharepoint job.
4. To configure the main site is affecting the subsites and causes the deletion of the list.

I think that options 1,2 it are not happening.

Everything would be resolved if we have access to central administration or even to some log, but for security reasons we don't have access to them, what is really bad for us, as developers because we have to guess what is going on.

Can someone give some tips about how to identify this problem?

Please let me know about any more important  additional information that I havent written so far.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed not being able to read logs is very inconvenient.
Also, in CSOM, property *AllowDeletion* for List isn't exposed; as it is for SSOM instead.

The only way I'm thinking you have to intercept when this happens, is to create a custom Remote Event Receivers, which hooks *ListDeleting / ListDeleted* events

This should be a rather up-to-date and good start if you're new to RERs
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220048.aspx#RER

Comment: we have implemented the ListDeleting and ListDeleted events. Till today the list wasn't deleted, I'll let you know any news. Thanks for your suggestion.